# CSS vh for mobile browsers not working

Tags: html, css

I have a web page that has 4 DIVS, each div has the height set to 25vh. They should be displayed full page width.
When I look at the page using browserstack (iphone 5), the DIVs are correctly split into 4 equal heights when in portrait mode and there is no scrolling required.
When I look at the same page using browserstack (Galaxy S5, iphone 7), the DIVS are split into 4 equal heights when in portrait mode, but I have to scroll a little to see the bottom of the last div.
Any suggestions as to what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Could you provide a complete code example, please?

Comment: The content could be taller than 25vh

Comment: content longer than 25vh, ghost margins, and a million things... Please provide the code